# Automatically Scroll / Animate html content

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

Display a Schedule-Table: What I want and what I already did:

- Display two html-Pages (mostly each is a table) in one Page. These two
  Pages are generated from a Software, I would like to display them in
  one page (e.g. with iframe)
- If one or both of these pages are to height, I want them to animate
  scroll to the end, append the same page and animate again (endless
  animate scroll to top). This I did successfully with JQuery.
  The Problem:
- The animation needs a lot of CPU, on many Computers the animation is
  not smooth and the content is not readable anymore.

Example see here: 
http://www.clipp.de/V/EndlessScrollEinfach.html

What could be a better method?
Maybe convert the pages to display in Jpeg first and display it then.
But how will I convert html in jpeg or png?

Is it possible to load the page in background? I need to refresh the content after each full animation.

Thanks for ideas and help.

```js
$("#idIframeHeute1").load(function() {
                                                            this.style.height =
                                                            this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
                                                            heightTodayTable     = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
                                                            // alert("totalHeight: " + totalHeight + ",   hHeute:" + hHeute);
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            if(totalHeight <= (heightTodayTable))
                                                            {
                                                            $(".rectangle").animate({
                                                                                    bottom: heightTodayTable   // Width
                                                                                    }, scrollTime, 'linear' );  // Tempo
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                            $("#idIframeHeute2").hide();
                                                            $("#heuteDiv").css({
                                                                               position:'absolute',
                                                                               top: 50
                                                                               });
                                                            
                                                            }
                                                            

                                                            
                                                            });
```

Comment: _“The animation needs a lot of CPU, on many Computers the animation is not smooth and the content is not readable anymore”_ – those are problems you will have with any kind of “endless animation”, and especially the last one should make you think about whether it is smart to animate the whole thing to begin with. Often it is better to let users scroll through content at their own pace.

Comment: I have to display a schedule in a school. Sometimes the table is to height. There is no interaction with the user, just a information-screen. Thank you for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iframe, why don't you try ajax. Since its not a cross domain, it is possible and would work smooth.

```
$('#heuteDiv').load('VertretungsplanHeute.html').css({'height':'4804px'});
```

I guess some thing like that will do your job smoother.